Can I let people fight bears for profit?
Consider the following scenario, with phrasing and details from this Tumblr post (mirrored here, screenshot):

A for-profit business offers an interactive experience where a patron "step[s] into the ring" to fight a bear, "unarmed, mano a mano."
The business charges $25 USD for the experience.
The business advertises the experience, including the specific claim that no patron will be able to defeat a bear.

Is it legal to operate such a business for profit?
The fight may be in a boxing ring or a cage. No waivers of liability are mentioned, but answers may require them. Answers may differentiate between different species of bear.
Note that this question is constrained to for-profit operations because, for $15 USD (according to the 2024 fee schedule), the State of Alaska permits visitors to enter Denali National Park; any sufficiently-motivated individual may already go fight a grizzly bear.

"any sufficiently-motivated individual may already go fight a grizzly bear" I think if it can be proven that you attacked the bear on purpose, you will soon find out how the law works.

@Corbin Regarding your last update, it's already a federal offense to simply approach a grizzly bear.  See here

@PeterM: It is an offense to "harass" a grizzly bear, yes. It is not an offense to be in Denali on a day pass and have a grizzly bear come within striking distance, as happened to me on my last visit to Alaska. See also the reasonable person hint given by the original source, who suggests that a reasonable person would think, "no I can't [fight a bear], they're bears."

@PeterM: That said, if you'd like to write an answer that expressly ignores the for-profit constraint, then I'd welcome it. I think that your point is interesting enough to be explored further.

@Corbin Saying "any sufficiently-motivated individual may already go fight a grizzly bear" implies you are approaching the bear, not the other way around.

So are you suggesting that "enter Denali, wander around for an arbitrarily long time until a grizzly attacks you, then fight it" is equivalent to "step into the ring and fight a bear", other than the profit motive? "Step into the ring" suggests a fight at a well defined time and place, initiated and orchestrated by human agency.

It was legal in the 1980s because I attended an event.

germany
No

Tierschutzgesetz
§ 1
[...] Niemand darf einem Tier ohne vernünftigen Grund Schmerzen, Leiden oder Schäden zufügen.

Source
Translation:

Animal Welfare Act
§ 1
[...] No person shall cause pain, suffering or harm to an animal without reasonable cause.

And no, "but it's fun" is not a "reasonable cause". If you want to know in detail, there is pages full of obvious reasonable causes and exceptions, butchers, veterinarians, clinical trials and more. "I am a business man and I think I can make a buck" is not one of them.

Suppose the human combatant were rendered unable to harm the bear (perhaps as part of the guarantee that no patron will be able to defeat the bear).  That would seem to be permissible under the provision cited here.

You can have friendly, non-harmful competition with animals, for example playing tug-of-war with your dog. Can I imagine a scenario where you play chess against a brain-bear, or stare down a superbly trained bear, or arm-wrestle one? Sure, in a comic book. But I see no valid combination of the words "fight a bear in a cage or boxing ring" that comes down to a painless, fun contest.

@nvoigt While I agree with you, now I'm wondering about bears in circuses.

@PeterM In all the circuses I know, "dancing bears" are no longer part of the show since many decades. Actually, very few animals appear there these days.

@PMF I have't been to a circus with animals in decades, but they still exist, and there are at least 4 major circuses with animals in the US alone.

Bears are not people, so I suppose this answer speculates that a person would be able to cause "pain, suffering, or harm" to a bear with an unarmed strike.

@Corbin What about the pain and suffering put on the bear by being contained and forced to fight.  Animal cruelty laws exist for a reason.

@Corbin I simply go by the question: "Fight in a cage" is going to cause pain and/or harm to one or both participants. Assuming anything else is just being silly.

I wonder if there's any difference if we express it as "Can I let people get mauled by a bear for profit?" Unless the human is allowed to use a weapon, I don't think there's much danger to the bear.

@Corbin under german law, animals are a special class that is not humans and not items but can be property. The class of Animals has special protections in germany.

@Barmar In which case the personal injury lawyers would have a field day.  I doubt you can sign away your rights to an event that will at the very least severely injure you, and could even kill you.  Even Troy Hurtubise only tested his bear proof suit on himself.

@PeterM Didn't there use to be a thing where you could pay to \go in the ring against a boxing champ?

@Barmar There may have been so, but there is a huge difference between being in the ring with human who understands how dangerous the event could be, and being in the ring with an animal.

france
Nope
You are extremely likely coming across the animal cruelty statute (article 521-1 du code pénal).
Notice that this statute has a carveout for running of the bulls festivals (when an "uninterrupted historical tradition" exists). That clause is necessary because although those festivals are physically harmless to the bull, they are definitely stressful for the animal.
Your proposed scheme involves keeping the bear in a cage for extended periods of time, having patrons go and (try to) beat him up, possibly drugging the bear to make it more of an even fight. I see no plausible way to make it work.
Probably not with dwarves, either!
Every French (lawyer) schoolboy knows about the Morsang-sur-Orge case. An entertainment business hires a person of short stature to be thrown about by customers. The local mayor finds the practice unsavory and forbids it. The business sues and argues that the practice is safe and consensual on all parts; it still loses, because the mayor has police powers to enforce "public order", which includes respect for the dignity of humans.
Should you propose a "midget-boxing" attraction to your customers, the local mayor would probably be able to forbid it on a very parallel reasoning (offensive to human dignity).

united-states
No
All native species of bears are protected.
Also, animal cruelty is illegal.

I don't doubt you, but your answer would be improved by citations.

That list does not include "all native species of bears".  It omits the most common native bear species in the continental US: the American black bear, Ursus Americanus.

Regardless, in the USA, you may go to Denali National Park and fight a grizzly bear. I don't recommend it, and neither do the rangers, but in terms of lawfulness I think you'd have to argue that the interaction is an ESA Section 3 "harassment" leading to unlawful "taking" of wildlife, and the government has not argued that in previous bear attacks in Denali.

@Jen: Give me a few hours to do the research. I have to do a state-by-state analysis here and I have a hand injury. I just thought that it should be clear that I'm not really expecting this answer to get better.

@Corbin: I don't see how the grizzlies in Denali have anything to do with your question. Obviously you may fight a bear in self defense, in the case of an encounter which you did not instigate or provoke.  That's completely different from the situation posited in your original question, in which the encounter is deliberately orchestrated.
